# Изменение глубины отрисовки виджетов

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, gui, qlabel

Как мне изменить глубину отрисовки виджетов, чтобы я мог рисовать один виджет поверх другого?

Comment: Пока что я использую чередование вызова метода show виджетов в том порядке, в котором желаю отрисовывать их. Это решает проблему. Однако, если мне будет нужно изменить глубину отрисовки виджета вдальнейшем? Как реализовать изменение глубины без использования методов hide и show? Ведь такая реализация приведёт к "исчезновению" виджетов на короткое время

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

Пожалуйста, всегда публикуйте минимально-воспроизводимый пример.
Это позволит правильно понять ваш вопрос и дать вам правильные рекомендации.

Если я вас правильно понял, то на самом деле все просто,
чтобы отрисовать виджет `B` поверх виджета `A` ,
сделайте родителем виджета `B` виджет `A` и все. Попробуйте:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: #7ff;")
        
        self.label_1 = QLabel(
            "label_1", 
            styleSheet="background-color: #77f; font-size: 170pt;"
        )

        self.label_2 = QLabel(
            "<i style='color: #f77;'>label_2</i>", 
            self.label_1,                                                    # !!! label_1
            alignment=Qt.AlignCenter,
            styleSheet="font-size: 120pt; background: transparent;"
        )

        self.label_3 = QLabel(
            "<b style='color: #5f5;'>label_3</b>", 
            self.label_2,                                                    # !!! label_2
            alignment=Qt.AlignCenter,
            styleSheet="font-size: 70pt; background: transparent;"
        )
        
        layout = QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label_1, 0, 0, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.label_2.resize(self.label_1.size()) 
        self.label_3.resize(self.label_1.size())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]