# Событие перемещения мыши mouseMoveEvent срабатывает вне пределов графика

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt, mousemoveevent, qrubberband

Есть основной класс `MainWindow()`, в нем подключаю событие через кнопку "**`gross_`**", которое отрабатывает движение мыши в классе `MyFilter()` все это работает, как нужно.

Теперь нужно использовать класс `QRubberBand()` (класс QRubberBand() предоставляет прямоугольник или линию, которые могут обозначать выделение или границу).

Нашел пример в интернете и скопировал:
подключаю события посредством кнопки "**`handleButton`**" через класс `ResizableRubberBand()`,
срабатывает только вне пределов графика (справа верхний угол).

Как сделать, чтобы захватывались график и области вне пределов графика?

Планирую добавлять дополнительные графики и рисовать вертикальную линию, с помощью `QRubberBand()`
поверх всех графиков.

Все это, если можно сделать в классе `MyFilter()`, так как для этой цели его и создавал, но не получилось подключить в него класс `ResizableRubberBand()`.

**main.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets, QtChart


mas =[1.33, 1.15, 1.55, 1.65, 1.64, 1.91, 1.33, 2.3, 1.5, 1.35, 2.52, 1.77, 1.7, 1.87, 2.0, 1.55, 1.73, 2.1,
              1.33, 1.15, 1.55, 1.92, 1.64, 1.91, 1.33, 1.71, 1.5, 1.35, 1.22, 1.77, 1.7, 1.87, 2.7, 1.55, 1.73, 2.1,
              1.33, 1.15, 1.55, 1.92, 1.64, 1.91, 1.33, 1.71, 1.5, 1.35, 1.22, 1.77, 1.7, 1.87, 2.0, 1.55, 1.73, 2.1]
x = len(mas)
x_ = x - 1


class MyFilter(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
         QtCore.QObject.__init__(self, parent)
         self.parent = parent

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.HoverMove:
            chart_view = self.parent.splitter.widget(0)
            if isinstance(chart_view, QtChart.QChartView):
                chart = chart_view.chart()
                s = chart.series()

        return False

class ResizableRubberBand(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        print("ResizableRubberBand")
        super(ResizableRubberBand, self).__init__(parent)

        self.draggable = False
        self.mousePressPos = None
        self.mouseMovePos = None

        self._band = QtWidgets.QRubberBand(QtWidgets.QRubberBand.Rectangle, self)
        self._band.setGeometry(550, 550, 550, 550)
        self._band.show()
        self.show()


    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
            if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
                self.mousePressPos = event.globalPos()                # global
                self.mouseMovePos = event.globalPos() - self.pos()    # local
                self.draggable = True
            elif event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
                self.position = QtCore.QPoint(event.pos())
                self.upper_left = self.position
                self.lower_right = self.position
                self.mode = "drag_lower_right"
                self._band.show()
            print("mousePressEvent")

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.draggable and event.buttons() & QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
            globalPos = event.globalPos()
            print(globalPos)
            diff = globalPos - self.mouseMovePos
            self.move(diff)
            self.mouseMovePos = globalPos - self.pos()
        elif self._band.isVisible():
            # visible selection
            if self.mode is "drag_lower_right":
                self.lower_right = QtCore.QPoint(event.pos())
                # print(str(self.lower_right))
            elif self.mode is "drag_upper_left":
                self.upper_left = QtCore.QPoint(event.pos())
                # print(str(self.upper_left))
            # update geometry
            self._band.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(self.upper_left, self.lower_right).normalized())
        print("mouseMoveEvent")

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.draggable = False
        print("mouseReleaseEvent")

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, start = 1, parent=None):
        self.start = start
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setMouseTracking(True)

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        self.gross = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.gross.setText("Gross")
        self.gross.clicked.connect(self.gross_)

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Show Rubber Band')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.label.setScaledContents(True)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft | QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('image.png'))

        self.hbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.gross)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.button)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.label)

        self.splitter = QtWidgets.QSplitter(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)

        self.lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
        self.lay.insertLayout(0, self.hbox)
        self.lay.addWidget(self.splitter, stretch=1)

        self.chart_view = QtChart.QChartView()
        self.chart = QtChart.QChart()
        self.line_serie = QtChart.QLineSeries()
        for i, value in enumerate(mas):
            self.line_serie.append(QtCore.QPointF(i, value))
        self.chart.addSeries(self.line_serie)
        self.chart.createDefaultAxes()
        self.chart_view.setChart(self.chart)
        self.splitter.addWidget(self.chart_view)

    def gross_(self):
        self.filter = MyFilter(self)
        self.installEventFilter(self.filter)

    def handleButton(self):
        self.band = ResizableRubberBand(self.label)
        print("handleButton")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow(start = 0)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как сделать, чтобы захватывались график и области вне пределов графика.

Вам надо передать родителя `self.central_widget`

```
self.band = ResizableRubberBand(self.central_widget)
```

и установить размер для класса `ResizableRubberBand`

```
self.resize(self.window().size())
```

---

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets, QtChart


mas =[
    1.33, 1.15, 1.55, 1.65, 1.64, 1.91, 1.33, 2.3, 1.5, 1.35, 2.52, 1.77, 
    1.7, 1.87, 2.0, 1.55, 1.73, 2.1, 1.33, 1.15, 1.55, 1.92, 1.64, 1.91, 
    1.33, 1.71, 1.5, 1.35, 1.22, 1.77, 1.7, 1.87, 2.7, 1.55, 1.73, 2.1,
    1.33, 1.15, 1.55, 1.92, 1.64, 1.91, 1.33, 1.71, 1.5, 1.35, 1.22, 1.77, 
    1.7, 1.87, 2.0, 1.55, 1.73, 2.1
]
x = len(mas)
x_ = x - 1


class MyFilter(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
         QtCore.QObject.__init__(self, parent)
         self.parent = parent

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.HoverMove:
            chart_view = self.parent.splitter.widget(0)
            if isinstance(chart_view, QtChart.QChartView):
                chart = chart_view.chart()
                s = chart.series()
        return False


class ResizableRubberBand(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        print("ResizableRubberBand")
        super(ResizableRubberBand, self).__init__(parent)
        
        self.resize(self.window().size())                                   # +++ <<<-----

        self.draggable = False
        self.mousePressPos = None
        self.mouseMovePos = None

        self._band = QtWidgets.QRubberBand(QtWidgets.QRubberBand.Rectangle, self)
        self._band.setGeometry(550, 550, 550, 550)
        self._band.show()
        self.show()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
            if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
                self.mousePressPos = event.globalPos()                # global
                self.mouseMovePos = event.globalPos() - self.pos()    # local
                self.draggable = True
            elif event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
                self.position = QtCore.QPoint(event.pos())
                self.upper_left = self.position
                self.lower_right = self.position
                self.mode = "drag_lower_right"
                self._band.show()
            print("mousePressEvent")

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.draggable and event.buttons() & QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
            globalPos = event.globalPos()
            print(globalPos)
            diff = globalPos - self.mouseMovePos
            self.move(diff)
            self.mouseMovePos = globalPos - self.pos()
        elif self._band.isVisible():
            # visible selection
            if self.mode is "drag_lower_right":
                self.lower_right = QtCore.QPoint(event.pos())
                # print(str(self.lower_right))
            elif self.mode is "drag_upper_left":
                self.upper_left = QtCore.QPoint(event.pos())
                # print(str(self.upper_left))
            # update geometry
            self._band.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(self.upper_left, self.lower_right).normalized())
        print("mouseMoveEvent")

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.draggable = False
        print("mouseReleaseEvent")


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, start = 1, parent=None):
        self.start = start
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        
#       vvvv <-------------------------------------------------------<!
        self.central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()                   # ^ self.
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)

        self.gross = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.gross.setText("Gross")
        self.gross.clicked.connect(self.gross_)

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Show Rubber Band')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.label.setScaledContents(True)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft | QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('Ok.png'))            # 'image.png' установите свое !!!

        self.hbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.gross)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.button)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.label)

        self.splitter = QtWidgets.QSplitter(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)

        self.lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.central_widget)
        self.lay.insertLayout(0, self.hbox)
        self.lay.addWidget(self.splitter, stretch=1)

        self.chart_view = QtChart.QChartView()
        self.chart = QtChart.QChart()
        self.line_serie = QtChart.QLineSeries()
        for i, value in enumerate(mas):
            self.line_serie.append(QtCore.QPointF(i, value))
        self.chart.addSeries(self.line_serie)
        self.chart.createDefaultAxes()
        self.chart_view.setChart(self.chart)
        self.splitter.addWidget(self.chart_view)

    def gross_(self):
        self.filter = MyFilter(self)
        self.installEventFilter(self.filter)

    def handleButton(self):
#        self.band = ResizableRubberBand(self.label)                     # - self.label
        self.band = ResizableRubberBand(self.central_widget)             # + self.central_widget
        self.band.show()                                                 # +  
        print("handleButton")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow(start = 0)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, большое! Сам наверное не смог бы месяцы сделать)

Comment: @inquirer судя потому что вы собираетесь делать дальше, думаю вам будет полезно https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1196598/pyqt5-%d0%98%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b3%d0%bb%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0/1211408#1211408